# How do I use SpeechRecognitionEngine in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, speech-recognition

I have been trying to get speech recognition working from a Windows Service without much luck.  I am able to get it working just fine from a Console, winForms or WPF application, but when I try to put the same code into a Service.  I based my sample console app on the example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554584.aspx  Then I literally copied the same code to the service and it fails.  I did read somewhere that the account that the Services run in don't have a access to a default audio device, so the problem lies with this line:

```
recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
```

Is there some way I can get speech recognition from a microphone working from within a service?

Comment: Windows services are non interactive. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: [It looks like somebody else already ran into this, and shares a workaround.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369521/speechhypothesized-event-not-raised

Comment: @Oded - This is for a home automation system that runs as a windows service.  I am trying to add voice recognition.

Comment: @G_P - Thanks, but in that question he never really solved it.  His answer was to just call a console application to do the speech recognition.

Comment: Also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377673/speech-recognition-engine-not-firing-event-in-windows-service

Answer (score 1):

It is probably a permissions problem. Run "services.msc", double-click on your service to edit it, and specify an account on the Log On tab. Use the account where you are able to run successfully as a console application.