# Speech Recognition Engine Not Firing Event in Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, speech-recognition

So I have a windows service with speech recognition implemented using the system.speech recognition engine. My speech recognition code runs fine when I start the service but no events for speech recognized fires. The strange thing is, if I run the exact same code, but in a console or WPF app instead, the event firing for speech recognition works just fine. 
I have already attached a debugger to my service process to check what was going on behind the scenes. It seems as though the speech recognition engine properly loads the grammars, sets its mode to listen continuously, and properly sets up the speech recognized event. No exceptions are thrown so I am not too sure what is wrong here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the microphone or processing a WAV file? I'm not sure how the audio plumbing will work in a service if you are trying to use the default audio device. If you are trying to convert from audio files or a stream, make sure you are using an InProc recognizer.

If you are creating a server app, you probably should consider using the Microsoft.Speech API and the server recongizers. See [What is the difference between System.Speech.Recognition and Microsoft.Speech.Recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977338/what-is-the-difference-between-system-speech-recognition-and-microsoft-speech-re) and the Microsoft Speech Platform SDK - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

If you are trying to do continuous recognition without your app in the foreground, I believe the shared recognizer may be able to support your need. The Microsoft desktop recognizer that ships in Windows 7 and Vista can work in two modes:  inproc or shared. Shared recognizers are useful on the desktop where voice commands are used to control any open applications. In System.Speech you can use [SpeechRecognizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.aspx) to access the shared desktop recognizer or [SpeechRecognitionEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.aspx) to have a dedicated inproc recognizer for your application. You might be able to use the shared recognizer to provide continuous recognition to your application even when your app is not in the foreground.

There is a very good article that was published a few years ago at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163663.aspx. It is probably the best introductory article I’ve found so far. It says:

> ...recognition engine can be instantiated in another process called
>   SAPISVR.EXE. This provides a shared recognition engine that can be
>   used simultaneously by multiple applications. This design has a number
>   of benefits. First, recognizers generally require considerably more
>   run-time resources than synthesizers, and sharing a recognizer is an
>   effective way to reduce the overhead. Second, the shared recognizer is
>   also used by the built-in speech functionality of Windows Vista.
>   Therefore, apps that use the shared recognizer can benefit from the
>   system's microphone and feedback UI. There's no additional code to
>   write, and no new UI for the user to learn.New to SAPI 5.3

Comment: I am using a microphone and am not creating a server app.

Comment: I don't know if you can use the default audio device in a service. What is your use case? If you are trying to do continuous recognition without your app in the foreground, I believe the shared recognizer may be able to support your need.

Comment: Yes my app needs to basically continuously listen for speech in the background. What exactly do you mean by shared recognizer?

Comment: I updated my answer to include some more info that I hope is helpful.

Comment: I understand that the shared recognizer might work since it is designed to work with multiple applications, however would I would like to figure out is why exactly the inproc recognition engine does not work with a windows service. I mean the inproc recognition engine works in a wpf application even if the wpf app is not the foreground application.

Comment: I don't know, but services interacting with devices is a tricky thing and usually should be avoided. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683502(VS.85).aspx, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327618, http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/accessing-dshow-devices-service-help-25209092.html.

Comment: Ah I see. Well at least this gives me an idea of what is wrong. I will post back here if I ever solve.

Answer (score 4):

The SpeechRecognition should be run on seperate thread and is coming OOTB from SpeechRecognitionEngine , should something like that:

```
static ManualResetEvent _completed = null;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     _completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
     SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
     _recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); // request for recognizer update
     _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("test")) Name = { "testGrammar" }); // load a grammar
     _recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); // request for recognizer update
     _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit")) Name = { "exitGrammar" }); // load a "exit" grammar
     _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizer_SpeechRecognized; 
     _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input of the speech recognizer to the default audio device
     _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
     _completed.WaitOne(); // wait until speech recognition is completed
     _recognizer.Dispose(); // dispose the speech recognition engine
} 
void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Result.Text == "test") // e.Result.Text contains the recognized text
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The test was successful!");
     } 
     else if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
     {
         _completed.Set();
     }
}
```

Also had a problem similar when i used SpeechRecognition and not SpeechRecognitionEngine. 
the above is a great sample of the usage + its listenining to events in another thread.
p.s: i got the reference from a great article:
[Speech recognition, speech to text, text to speech, and speech synthesis in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a) have
Fun :)

Comment: If you use RequestRecognizerUpdate, I think you should then use RecognizerUpdateReached event handler to call LoadGrammar, plus you would do all LoadGrammar calls together in that event handler. However, if the recognizer is not started yet, there shouldn't be any need to call RequestRecognizerUpdate in the first place (can remove it)

Comment: btw, a pattern I've come up at SpeechLib (http://SpeechLib.codeplex.com) after lots of trial and error to load a grammar when speech recognition is already started is mentioned at the end of https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/howto-pause-and-resume-speech-recognition-with-microsoft-engines

Comment: @Robocide upvoted! I was doing something similar - queueing multiple speech recognition jobs and this helped me (using `ManualResetEvent` and `WaitOne()`. I was trying to figure out how to dispose the existing `_recognizer` for the next task in the queue as [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd146960(v=office.14).aspx) states that "calling `Dispose()` in an event handler is **not** advised". Hope it helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the service to be allowed to interact with the desktop?

[image]

I believe that interaction with user interfacing devices like a microphone is covered by this setting.

Comment: I thought that might have been the issue but it does not fix it :(

Answer (score 1):

If @Robocide answer does not work for you, like in my case, all you have to do is to declare the SpeechRecognitionEngine as a field instead of a local variable in your Main method.

Example:

```
    private SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = null; //make the speeach recognition engine a private field
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
         _recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); // request for recognizer update
         _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("test")) Name = { "testGrammar" }); // load a grammar
         _recognizer.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); // request for recognizer update
         _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit")) Name = { "exitGrammar" }); // load a "exit" grammar
         _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizer_SpeechRecognized; 
         _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input of the speech recognizer to the default audio device
         _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
         _recognizer.Dispose(); // dispose the speech recognition engine
    } 

void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Result.Text == "test") // e.Result.Text contains the recognized text
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The test was successful!");
     } 
}
```

If you notice, I removed the ManualResetEvent because it does not allow some processes to run if a speech has not been recognized.